# How to delete an specific line of a file using POSIX shell scripts?

Tags: awk, sed, sh, posix, ed

I want do delete, say line number three of the file `a`. How can I do this with tools like `sed` or `awk` in a way that it's compatible with the POSIX specification? I know I could do `sed -i '3d' a`, but the `-i` flag is not specified by POSIX for `sed`.

Of course I could run the same `sed` command without the `-i` flag, save to a temporary file and then replace the original file with the new one; but I would prefer a one-liner.

Comment: Not sure on POSIX, but can you use `ed`? `ed -s file <<< $'3d\nwq'`

Comment: @MarkSetchell wonderful! Can you post your answer, please? That should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I have no idea on POSIX compliance so I’d rather defer to @CharlesDuffy before posting...

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm quite sure that `echo '3d\nwq' | ed -s file` is POSIX compliant. `<<<` is not part of the POSIX specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure about POSIX compliance, but can suggest using `ed` to delete the third line of a file as follows:

```
echo $'3d\nwq' | ed -s YourFile
```

or, maybe

```
printf "3d\nwq\n" | ed -s YourFile
```

Comment: The use of `printf` should be strongly preferred over `echo` if portability is a concern. `$'...'` C-style strings are a Bash extension, and not supported in POSIX.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I didn't needed to use `$'...'`. I just used `echo '3d\nwq' | ed -s file`.

@tripleee, why should `printf` be preferred over `echo`?

Comment: Requiring `echo` to support `\n` isn't portable, either. The many incompatible versions of `echo` is precisely the reason you should use `printf` instead, which is strictly specified by POSIX. (Embedding a literal newline between the quotes should work fine with all versions of `echo` too, though.)

Answer (score 2):

Following may help here.

```
awk -v line=3 'FNR==line{next} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

`-v line=3`: Means creating `awk` variable named line whose value is 3 here as per your post.

`FNR==line`: Checking condition here if line number(awk's out of the box variable) value is equal to variable line value.

`{next}`: If condition mentioned above is TRUE then putting next will skip all further statements and nothing will happen on 3rd line of Input_file.

`1`: `awk` works on method of condition and action so by mentioning `1` making condition as TRUE and not mentioning any action so by default print of line will happen.

In case you want to save output into same Input_file itself then append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` to above code too.

---

Or with `sed` in case `-i` option is not there.

```
sed '3d' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

POSIX `sed` page:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html

Comment: Well, I already knew the `sed` command. The question is if there's a single command that can do the job, instead of squashing all the commands in a single line with `&&`s or `;`s.

Comment: @LuisLavaire, since you told `-i` option is not working so that is work around for it, also I added explanation to now, let me know?

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work: it's that the `-i` flag is (specific?) for the GNU's `sed`. I need to make my script POSIX-compliant.

Comment: @LuisLavaire, since I don't have POSIX `sed` with me so can't confirm but after searching seems like it is not there see this http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html

Comment: As you can see, the `-i` flag is not specified by POSIX.

Comment: Like `sed`, Awk doesn't support overwriting the destination file (though GNU Awk has an option for this); so this has the same flaw as `sed` without `-i`.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly shorter version then Ravinder his script is :

```
awk '(FNR!=3)' input_file
```

An awk program is composed of pairs of the form:

```
pattern { action }
```

Either the `pattern` or the `action` (including the enclosing brace characters) can be omitted. A missing `pattern` shall match any record of input, and a missing `action` shall be equivalent to: `{ print }`.

The `pattern` in this case states checks *If the line-number of the file (`FNR`) is different from `3`*. If true, perform the default action (`{print $0}`).

The deletion of the line would read then :

```
$ awk '(FNR!=3)' input_file > tmp_file && mv tmp_file input_file
```

Comment: `'NR!=3'` would be even shorter.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I agree. I wrote `FNR` intentionally to make people aware of its existence. It also fits a bit better as 'File Number of Record' and not the overall 'Record Number'

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR!=3{a[++nr]=$0} END{for (i=1;i<=nr;i++) print a[i] > FILENAME}' file
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the entire file is read and closed prior to execution of `END` then?

Comment: It is guaranteed that the entire file is read, whether or not it's closed I couldn't find in the POSIX spec given how much time I was willing to spend looking at it. It's also guaranteed that it will be opened by `>` if not already open.